# Cloud Firestore for android apps built in Kivymd not working with buildozer

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, kivy, buildozer

Me and a friend are creating android app in Kivymd. We did create a database using firebase.
But we used the firestore option than the realtime database. We really like the feature and want to keep it. Everything works fine when we compile the app on our Ubuntu environment. But when we add firebase-admin in our requirements in the buildozer.spec file we get alot of errors related to google-cloud, google-protobuf and the list goes on. We have been looking everywhere on the internet but we cant find a solution. And all of these packages are installed with pip and we have verified this.

When using our original requirements string such as:
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc3,kivymd,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,android,plyer,requests,urllib3,chardet,idna,hostpython3

Everything works fine, but when we add firebase_admin to the requirements we get No module errors that makes the requirements string getting very long. And we have installed everything u can possibly think related to the google packages with pip.

We have been exploring on maybe creating our own recipe, but we would be very happy if anyone could just lead us in the right direction. Our current requirements string is so long that i wont post it here. We have made realtime database work because it only uses requests so maybe we need to skip using firestore. Below are the packages we use to use and are the root cause of why the app does not work in the android app with buildozer.

import firebase_admin

from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, exceptions

I have a feeling we must create a recipe or that its not even possible to use with kivymd and android. But any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I think this is hard to understand what exactly is going on. It would be the best to create reproducible example (described here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or at least format this question in the way community will knew what is code, what is error massage, what is issue description.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: We did a workaround for this and if you still have troubles i would be happy to tell you how we did it.

Comment: did you solve this issue yet ? @winter